# Do all homogeneous systems with non-trivial solutions have columns of zeros?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to think about this problem I'm faced with.

My peer stated that a non-trivial homogeneous system (which is square) has a column/row of zeros, but I'm trying to make sense of that. It's pretty mind-boggling at the moment. Can anyone help?

Comment: In row-reduced form, yes -- we have a zero row (but not necessarily zero column).

Comment: but is there an arbitrary example to show that?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ has no zero row but reduces to $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$. I will write up an answer to expand on things.

Comment: If the matrix is not required to be square, however, then it is possible to have no zero rows and no zero columns. Consider for example $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$, which cannot be reduced further, but it has a non-trivial solution (e.g. $(0,1,-1)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a homogeneous system with $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns. What this represents is the system $Ax = 0$ for some square matrix $A$. To say that there is a non-trivial solution to this system means that there is a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Ax = 0$. That is, the null space of $A$ has a nonzero vector, and hence it has dimension at least 1. By the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of the matrix is strictly less than the number of columns. But this corresponds to saying that the row-reduced echelon form of the matrix has at most $n - 1$ pivot columns. Hence there is at least one zero row.

However, it is not necessarily the case that we always have a zero column. Consider $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ which has RREF of $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$. This has no zero column, but it has a non-trivial solution, e.g. $(1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

A nontrivial solution to a homogeneous system indicates that the nullity is $\ge1$.  By the rank- nullity theorem, the rank is not full.  Thus in rref, there's a row of zeros.  (For the rref is upper triangular, and without a row of zeros, the determinant will be nonzero.)